# VB 2013 Access DB Dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, ms-access-2010

Rewriting a legacy system in VB 2013 Express which connects to an Access DB.  I've set up the Data Connection and have a DataSet with all the tables.  The code needs to do the following:

Delete all the rows in the "extract" table;
  Read in and parse the new data; 
  Write the new data to the "extract" table.

I've got the reading and parsing part done, but I need help with the deleting and writing part.  Nothing I try seems to work.

This is what i've tried:

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CLI_CRVM.accdb") 
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand() 
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text 
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM extract" 
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1
```

Comment: Ugh, I can't even use this forum correctly!  I tried this:  Dim sqlConnection1 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CLI_CRVM.accdb")

        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM extract"
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

Comment: I tried deleting a single row this way:  'Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet1()
        Dim extractTableAdapter As New DataSet1TableAdapters.extractTableAdapter()

        extractTableAdapter.Delete(1)
        extractTableAdapter.Update()'

Comment: When working with MS Access, make sure all your SQL commands end with `;`. IE, "DELETE FROM extract;". They will not execute without that.

Comment: That's what I thought, @Steve  However, the MSDN article I found did not have the semi-colon: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233823.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb

Comment: @Steve No, the final semi-colon is not an absolute requirement. In fact, it is almost always superfluous.

Comment: What namespace do I need for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `System.Data.SqlClient`, but that is specifically for working with Microsoft SQL Server databases. The example code in your question will fail with

> Keyword not supported: 'provider'.

For an OLEDB connection to your Access database, use `System.Data.OleDb`.

Comment: Thanks for the help - that was the key.  However, even though the code runs and I get a return of '10' from the ExecuteNonQuery, the rows are not deleted.  I can run the SQL manually on the DB.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user3850146 Make sure that your `OleDbConnection` is closed properly. It is considered good form to work with your connection inside a [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/htd05whh.aspx) block. I prefer to `.Close()` explicitly, although others advocate that the end of the Using block will automatically `.Close()` the connection for you.

Comment: Here's what I've got:  
Dim sqlConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CLI_CRVM.accdb")
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand()

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM [extract] ;"
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection
        Dim intRC As Integer
        sqlConnection.Open()
        intRC = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'sqlConnection.Close()
        MsgBox(intRC)